# Visual studio code Python input not taking input

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input

When trying to use the input function in Visial Studio Code on Mac it does not let me type the input in the output window as illustrated below, resulting in the program getting stuck. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
[Input example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipMLP.png)

Comment: You may have to click on the Output window just to the right of `something?`.

Comment: No, I can't type anywhere in the output window, the cursor is there, it doesn't let me type or press enter to register and empty string.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Windows. My VSC runs the program in the `Terminal` tab.

Comment: I can run it from the terminal, it's just VSC that does not work and gets stuck infinitely.